# Variable logued use with mysql captive portal

Tags: mysql

Portal and works

Initially to prove I have the captive portal pointing to the LAN but in the project point to the WAN as it controls access into the network there is a service that I want to get out but the port does not open and without portal from outside not I see the service. I would also like to know how I can with mysql I have in the internal network get the pass around the variable that stores the amount of achieved at a certain time and do things with it in mysql is the number. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help ) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you want.  I take it that English is not your native language.  I'm not sure what the rules are for non-English posts, but if you could add what you are looking for in your native language below, someone (perhaps I) could help you better.  Perhaps Google Translate might help.

Comment: @TGray: Please don't ask users to post in their native language.  Stack Overflow is an *English* only site, although some localised versions do exist: [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/), [pt.so], [ru.so] and [ja.so].

Comment: What I had suggested was that he leave his original post and then add it, or a Google Translation afterwards.  I'm sorry to have broken protocol.  Apologies.  Just trying to help him out.